# I need help about an error called " ReferenceError: message is not defined. "

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Here is my code:

```
let xpAdd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 8;
console.log(xpAdd);
if (!xp[message.author.id]) {
  xp[message.author.id] = {
    xp: 0,
    level: 1
  };
}
```

Here is the error:

> ReferenceError: `message` is not defined.

Comment: Can u guys give me the actual code? I've been trying to fix it and is still cant

Comment: You've been provided "actual code" in both answers. What have you tried and what exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The key passed to xp is not defined,  so you need to define it first

```
let xpAdd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 8
var message = {
  author:{
    id: //*whatever id you want to access*
  }
}
console.log(xpAdd);
if(!xp[message.author.id]){
xp[message.author.id] = {
  xp: 0,
  level: 1
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`message` has not been defined anywhere within the very limited code you've shown.

If your code is inside of your own function, pass `message` as a parameter:

```js
function addXP(message) {
  ...
}

addXP(message);
```

Otherwise, your code should be inside of your client's `message` event callback. In that case, you can declare `message` as the Message parameter:

```js
client.on('message', message => {  // Client may be defined as 'bot' instead of 'client'
  ...
});
```

---

MDN Documentation:
[parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Parameter)
[scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)
[functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Discord.js Documentation:
[`message` Event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message)
[`Message` Class](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message)